# Lines from 2 Breakers, Terminiating in Single Box

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I just found that one of my outlets was wired with wires from 2 seperate breakers feeding it. Meaning I had to turn off both breakers to kill the outlet (and they are not adjascent breakers that are joined with a pin so if one trips, both trips).
I am curious about my options with 2 breakers running into one box and your guys thoughts on which option may be best.

1. Add second outlet, each outlet would be connected to a single breaker.
   I feel like I've read some threads that this is acceptable provided it doesn't overload the box/breakers etc. My house is already a hodgepodge of wiring where there may be 4 breakers in a single room for just the outlets - but 2 breakers in a single box is not something I've seen in my house at least.
2. Cap one set of lines and only use the other.
   Both lines concluded in this box, so there's nothing 'downstream' that this should be interrupting. I could put a wire nut on the ends of one set of lines (a connector on each individual wire) and then just let them live in the box, though they'd technically be hot still.
   I'm inclined to do this approach as it'd be the simplest, and I don't have to cut in a double gang box. If this route is acceptable, I'd label the capped wires with which breaker they go to, and that they're still hot.

I'm really hoping I don't have to pull one of the lines back to its source and disconnect it, as I don't know where either comes from, and I just finished the room.

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: Can you upload pictures of the receptacle box showing the various wires coming in and pictures of the panel with the two breakers identified?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple proper ways you can handle these two separate circuits coming in to one outlet box. That on its own is not a problem.

1. This is fine, just make sure the two circuits' hots and neutrals are kept separate from each other. All grounds should still be tied together. An alternative that doesn't require adding a second outlet is to remove the tab separating the top and bottom outlet (for a standard single-gang duplex outlet), and wire one circuit to the top and one to the bottom. This is more common in kitchens where you might need to power multiple high-load devices, but you do it anywhere (think space heater plus entertainment center).
2. This is also fine, though if you know that one of these circuits only goes to this box, then you could disconnect it at the main panel as well and give yourself a free space for the future. If you can't remove the wire, wire nut both sides, mark both ends to indicate they are not in service (and not to be put back in service).

Comment: All power to a single yoke (e.g., top and bottom of a split duplex receptacle) **must** have common shutoff, meaning either double breaker or handle-tied pair. If you also share the neutral then it is called an MWBC (but note, you can't use a neutral from one cable to serve the hot in a different cable), which is what you find "common in kitchens".

Comment: @manassehkatz Interesting, I did not know such a rule existed for that case! Also a good note on MWBC. OP will need to determine if this is the situation (if done correctly, a MWBC will be in a single /3 wire instead of two separate /2 wires), as the breakers will need to be tied in the panel for that reason.